# Disable sleep mode in OS X with swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos

I made an OS X Application in Xcode and I want to keep my Mac from going to sleep when I have it open. I know in iOS Swift you use:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

But how do you do it with OS X Swift?

Comment: Take a look at the source for the `caffeinate` command: http://opensource.apple.com/source/PowerManagement/PowerManagement-321.2.9/caffeinate/caffeinate.c

Answer (score 15):

The current way is shown in [Technical QA 1340](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1340/_index.html). It's ostensibly about sleep and wake notifications, but check out listing 2, entitled "Preventing sleep using I/O Kit in Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard". You basically use `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName` to enter a state whereby sleep is disallowed, then call `IOPMAssertionRelease` when you're done.

I don't have sample code, as I've not personally used this, but it'd be pretty straightforward to port the code in the tech note to Swift.

**Update:** That API was *introduced* in 10.6, but still works fine in the latest OS, and as far as I know is still the preferred way to do it. Works in Swift, too.

```
import IOKit
import IOKit.pwr_mgt

let reasonForActivity = "Reason for activity" as CFString
var assertionID: IOPMAssertionID = 0
var success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName( kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep as CFString,
                                            IOPMAssertionLevel(kIOPMAssertionLevelOn), 
                                            reasonForActivity,
                                            &assertionID )
if success == kIOReturnSuccess {
    // Add the work you need to do without the system sleeping here.

    success = IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID);
    // The system will be able to sleep again.
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but this answer works for OS X 10.6. I have OS X 10.11. Also this code is in Objective-C. Swift didn't come about till OS X 10.9. I need code for Swift.

Comment: @NathanaelCarper This works perfectly in OS X 10.13. I refactored it into my own code, posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601453/using-swift-to-disable-sleep-screen-saver-for-osx/46519646#46519646).

Comment: Works well in OS X 10.13.6.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to prevent idle triggered sleep, IOCancelPowerCharge might work. But it won't work if something manually triggers the sleep

Comment: How would I do that? I couldn't find anything online that told me how to do it.