# Stopping Mac from sleeping while app is running

Tags: swift, macos

I want to stop a the user's Macbook from automatically sleeping while one the app is running. How would I do that? I have seen this

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1340/_index.html

and this:

[Disable sleep mode in OS X with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757229/disable-sleep-mode-in-os-x-with-swift)

and this:

[Using Swift to disable sleep/screen saver for OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37601453/using-swift-to-disable-sleep-screen-saver-for-osx/46519646#46519646)

But there is no simple line of code that I can put or a delegate method that makes this simple like there is in iOS? I just want to have the entire app work properly and stop the computer from automatically going to sleep. If someone puts in it to sleep manually, then obviously that is fine. I don't want to prevent the user from putting the computer to sleep. But as long as my app is running I don't want the computer to sleep. Like when you are watching a movie, the app does not go to sleep. How do I do that?

I feel like this is the code that I need but do I just run this function in the viewdidload and it will work? Is it that simple?

```
var assertionID: IOPMAssertionID = 0
var success: IOReturn?

func disableScreenSleep(reason: String = "Unknown reason") -> Bool? {
    guard success != nil else { return nil }
    success = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName( kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep as CFString,
                                       IOPMAssertionLevel(kIOPMAssertionLevelOn),
                                       reason as CFString,
                                       &assertionID )
    return success == kIOReturnSuccess
}
```

Comment: try this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143591/how-do-i-prevent-my-macbook-from-sleeping-when-downloading-apps-from-the-app-sto

Comment: Have you tried it? What didn't work? What problem are you having?

Comment: `guard success != nil else { return nil }` will always return nil. I would just remove it

Comment: should I just call the function in the view did load?

Comment: I'd appreciate that if you find a bug in the code I've provided in an answer, that you leave a comment pointing it out, instead of asking a new question about whether or not it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I already mentioned in comments you need to remove the guard otherwise it will simply return nil and will never disable the screen sleep. You can also simplify your method, return void and change your success property to a Bool property like disabled to monitor the screen sleep state:

```
var assertionID: IOPMAssertionID = 0
var sleepDisabled = false
func disableScreenSleep(reason: String = "Disabling Screen Sleep") {
    if !sleepDisabled {
        sleepDisabled = IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep as CFString, IOPMAssertionLevel(kIOPMAssertionLevelOn), reason as CFString, &assertionID) == kIOReturnSuccess
    }

}
func enableScreenSleep() {
    if sleepDisabled {
        IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID)
        sleepDisabled = false
    }

}
```

---

To disable the screen simply just call the method inside viewDidLoad of your first view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    disableScreenSleep()
    print("sleep Disabled:", sleepDisabled)
}
```

Comment: Using that code, you won't be able to re-enable sleeping if you call `disableScreenSleep` more than once before calling `enableScreenSleep`, unless the program quits.