# How to stop the screen from going to sleep

Tags: swift, macos, ipad, lockscreen

How to stop the screen from going to sleep in the iPad app on Mac (Designed for iPad)?

These solutions don't help "UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled=true", "NSApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true", [Insomnia](https://github.com/ochococo/Insomnia). Is there even a solution?

Comment: I don't think you can. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36975149/5133585

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunately this solution is not suitable